# How do I ORDER BY timestamp in this recursive query?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, recursive

I have a working reqursive query for my comments table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE comments_tree(
  id,
  content,
  created_at,
  path,
  level
) AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    content,
    created_at,
    ARRAY[id],
    1 as level
  FROM comments
  WHERE
    parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT
    comments.id,
    comments.content,
    comments.created_at,
    path || comments.id,
    comments_tree.level + 1 as level
  FROM comments_tree
  JOIN comments ON comments_tree.id = comments.parent_id
  WHERE NOT comments.id = ANY(path)
)
SELECT * FROM comments_tree ORDER BY path;
```

I have added 5 comments (2 of them have content 'parent x', others - 'child x').

Example of output (formatted to be more readable):

```
"-> parent 1: 16:49"
"--> child 1: 16:50"
"--> child 2: 16:51"
"--> child 3: 16:52"
"-> parent 2: 16:53"
```

I want to order comments by their creation time (`created_at` field) like this:

```
"-> parent 2: 16:53"
"-> parent 1: 16:49"
"--> child 3: 16:52"
"--> child 2: 16:51"
"--> child 1: 16:50"
```

How do I do that?

Comment: (1) Aren't your examples exchanged? The first one is the one ordered by creation time. (2) Have you just tried changing the last line of your query: `ORDER BY created_at` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Nothing was changed.

Comment: Basic requirement for this kind of questions: table definition showing relevant columns with data types and all constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statements). Most importantly: is `created_at UNIQUE NOT NULL`? Else it gets more complex. And your version of Postgres. Also: Are you trying to solve this for only 2 levels or for any number of levels? Sort by root timestamp of level, then by timestamp of each parent level recursively? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity I omit additional columns to focus on core of the problem.

#### Simple solution

Collect timestamps (`created_at`) in another array (`path_created`) like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
   SELECT id, created_at, ARRAY[id] AS path
        , ARRAY[created_at] AS path_created
   FROM   comments
   WHERE  parent_id IS NULL

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.created_at, path || c.id
        , t.path_created || c.created_at
   FROM   tree     t
   JOIN   comments c ON t.id = c.parent_id
   WHERE  NOT c.id = ANY(t.path)
   )
SELECT *
FROM   tree
ORDER  BY path_created[1] DESC, path[1] ASC
        , path_created[2] DESC, path[2] ASC
        , path_created[3] DESC, path[3] ASC
        , ...
```

*If two threads start at the same `created_at`, sort the smaller `id` first.*

... which is good enough for a low maximum number of elements. Works if there are fewer elements in the array. It's neither very dynamic nor very elegant for an unknown number of levels, though.

#### Dynamic number of levels

You could concatenate or calculate a single value from `created_at` and `id` or use a document type like `jsonb`. All of these solutions have corner cases. If you put some smarts into it, it'll be unambiguous.

The ***general, clean solution*** is to compute the row number for each row *per level* with [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE), ordered by any number of columns or expressions directly:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
   SELECT id, created_at, ARRAY[id] AS path
        , ARRAY[row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC, id ASC)] AS path_sort
   FROM   comments
   WHERE  parent_id IS NULL

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.created_at, t.path || c.id
        , t.path_sort || row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c.created_at DESC, c.id ASC)
   FROM   tree t
   JOIN   comments c ON t.id = c.parent_id
   WHERE  NOT c.id = ANY(path)
   )
SELECT *
FROM   tree
ORDER  BY path_sort;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2392140200cf245950f9a8d41e2aab88)*

`row_number()` breaks ties among peers in any case. In the example the added `id` to the `ORDER BY` clause of the window definition. Assuming it is the PK and therefore breaks ties in *deterministic* fashion.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! 
I changed your code a bit. 
Everythin works like a charm!